# Android webkit bug: white screen flashed (for < 1 second) when changing webview URLs

Tags: android, webview

Bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25722

Anyone has a workaround/ webcore hack for this reported bug? My client's website is made up of pages with a black background and the flashing white screen's really bad.

Android SDK - Ice cream sandwich

- Only happens when HW accleration is set to true

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the background of the WebView to black?

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(Color. BLACK);
```

Edit:

Sorry I completely overlooked the bug report.

I think setting to a software layer if the android version is ICS may be the safest / most reliable option:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    mWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

You may also want to include Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1

Comment: Thanks Gaunt. Although this snippet removes the flicker, it also causes webpages written with 'CSS3 3d transforms' to not load at all.

Comment: Another stab at this ;)

Could you wait for onPageStartedLoading and onPageFinishedLoading in either WebViewClient or WebViewChromeClient and toggle setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) and setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)?

Comment: The visibility workaround didn't work too. I even tested delaying the call to setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) a couple of seconds after the onPageFinished event. This time the flicker happens around the time setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically changing the parameters of glClearColor used by webkit to change the background worked for me. Webkit's libwebcore needs to be rebuilt! :)